# Call to sed works from command line but fails in script

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I've been using the following call to `sed` to remove lines files.

```
sed "/% Program:/,/mode: SPIKE/d" file.tt > file.tt.nh
```

I tried writing a bash script to allow me to run the script on many files at once. However `sed` fails.

```
sed "/% Program:/,/mode: SPIKE/d" file.tt > file.tt.nh
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `"'
```

This is the script I've written that isn't working

```
#!/bin/bash
SEDARG='"/% Program:/,/mode: SPIKE/d"';
for F in *.tt
do
  OUT=$F'.nh';
  echo 'sed '$SEDARG' '$F' > '$OUT;
  sed $SEDARG $F > $OUT
done
```

What perplexes me is if I copy the echo'd string and paste it in the command line it works fine.

Does anyone know why this script is failing but the command line call works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting is tricky. Basically, move the double quotes from where you *assign* to `$SEDARG` to where you *use* `$SEDARG`.

```
SEDARG='/% Program:/,/mode: SPIKE/d'
for F in *.tt
do
  OUT="$F.nh"
  echo "sed $SEDARG $F > $OUT"
  sed "$SEDARG" "$F" > "$OUT"
done
```

Comment: Just to expand on the use of quotes: they are only necessary to protect the characters intended for `sed` from the shell; `sed` doesn't care about and never sees the outer quotes. For example, `echo foo | sed s/foo/bar/` works as intended, since nothing in the `sed` script needs to be protected from shell interpretation.